# What are the alternate ways to avoid database call in android app?

Tags: android, xml, google-play

Well, I have uploaded an android application on Google play store which shows live channel of my country.

I just want to avoid Database call for fetching URLs for live channel. Now alternate in my mind is that upload an XML file so that android app reads URLs from that XML and if URLs are changed later, i can upload the new XML to Google play store again ?

Now how easy is it to upload to Google Play Store, will it be automatic update for users?

What are other alternatives for fetching Streaming URL from Database or XML ?

Comment: @Muhammad...I think you will store your file on server and at the time of launching the app first time you will download this file from server and stored it in your mobile and just simply read that links from the file..And you put sync button that will be download your file again from your server if any change is made in that file..I think its better solution..hope it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious, that you shouldn't hardcode the list of channels inside the APK (by putting it inside the XML or DB with the assets), nobody wants to update the app just because this list was changed. The easiest way is to put XML file on some server (you may want to take a look on [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/), they have great solution for keeping static content) and pull it either on the first run or on demand. Also you may want to use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to send either the message that list was updated or, if the size of the list is not very big, you can send the list itself via this service.

Answer (score 0):

You want to persist some information from server into your device:

1. Database
2. SharedPreferences
3. File ( which could be `XML` or any other format like `JSON`, even you can save one file per 
   channel with that channel name to avoid parsing, I suggest json format)